# Distribution in ranks

Tags: ranking

I'm developing a multiplayer game with a Glicko-based ranking system.

I started creating a system that assign one of 12 ranks out of the decimal rating of the player.

The rank boundaries are determined by the percentiles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile)

But I don't know to which percentiles can I set the boundaries to keep a smooooth distribution of the players in the ranks like in games like [CS:GO](https://csgosquad.com/ranks).

Answer (score 2):

Your game's *real distribution of players' rating* comes from your games' features and characteristics, including (but not limited to) teams's size and number, scores, victory conditions, and more.

Only if you know the *real distribution of players' rating* you can set *a smooooth distribution of the players in the ranks*, as per your question.

In [rankade](https://rankade.com), our multipurpose free ranking system for sports, games, and more, we noticed **significant differences** in rating scores' distribution for type of game and/or for 'families', mechanics, factions' set-ups, and more.

Comment: Your advertising is not even an answer to my question.

Comment: I try again, rewording my *answer*. It's *impossible* to set appropriate boundaries without knowing real distribution of scores, and our *experience* and *data* support this statement.